# iOS Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, navigator

I want to build an application with this kind of navigation between views:
a scrollview with text items (like a menu bar). Check Radio-Canada app on app store (free).

How to proceed? I know that I need a scrollview, but after that... You have to understand that I don't have too much experience with iOS 5.

Check this snapshot for an example:

[snap http://www.eazyrf.com/Snap2.jpg](http://www.eazyrf.com/Snap2.jpg)

Comment: Don't expect people to download an app from the App Store to understand your problem. People should be able to understand your problem from the information you put in your question.

Comment: I am a new user of this forum, I don't have the permission to leave an image for the moment.

Comment: Being new is a problem at all. However, the more details and relevant information you include in your post, the more likely you are to get a valuable answer. BTW: You should be able to reference an image if I am not mistaken like this: `![image title](http://server.com/image-url.png)`.

Comment: @Besi New users cannot post links or images.

Answer (score 2):

For a *horizontal* scrollview, just create a scrollview and add buttons to it. The white 'selected' background you clipped can be created by loading a white oval and using `resizeableImageWithCapInsets:` to extend it to fit the text. Link the button's `click` event to a function that presents the new view. If this 'menu bar' acts like a standard iOS tab bar, you'll need to manage the view hierarchy yourself.

For a *vertical* scrollview, most likely you're looking at a `UITableView` contained within a `UINavigationController`, where the class implementing `UITableViewDelegate` for the table view is responding to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` by pushing a new view onto the navigation controller. This is a common pattern to implement what looks like a scrolling list of items, where tapping on one cell causes a transition to a new screen.

Comment: Yes - the App Store app, the iTunes app, the Settings app, etc. Anywhere you see the > (greater-than) symbol at the right side of list, where tapping it causes a new view to scroll in from the right, that's a table view. The three examples I mentioned are also using a navigation bar and pushing/popping views there too.

Comment: Apple's iOS Developer Library pages have everything describing this and all the links to their sample code, including the UICatalog project.

Comment: Looks like you're talking about a Desktop-style menu bar. I extended this answer to discuss that case. You'll probably have to do quite a bit of programming to get this to work well -- IB itself won't suffice.